# C# Sql Command for Insering into a database

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am new to Visual C# programming language and recently i was trying to make a application that is supposed to insert into a local database of users some data but every times my code runs and the insertion works fine the database does not update.This is the code that i am using

```
try
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand();
    insert.CommandText = "insert into Clienti (Nume,Prenume,Parola,Email) values(@Nume,@Prenume,@Parola,@Email)";
    insert.Connection = cn;
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume", register_nume.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenume", register_prenume.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parola", register_password.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", register_email.Text);
    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader reader = insert.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read()) { }

    MessageBox.Show("Added succesfully");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
}
```

I already tried the property Copy to output and it doesn't seems to work.
I am sorry for any grammar mistakes that i made,I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: do you get any exceptions? what shows in your sql server logs?

Comment: I would actually expect the record to be inserted twice by the above code.    After calling `insert.ExecuteNonQuery()` you should have your new record added to the database-- but what are you expecting to happen by calling `insert.ExecuteReader()` with the same command text?

Comment: What do you mean with _database not update_? How do you check if your database table has no new rows?

Comment: I check my database by going to my table associated with my database and using Show Tables Data

Comment: I also forgot to ssy that i am using servife based database inside visual studio

Comment: This seems a totally different problem. Can you add to your question your connectionstring? (After removing sensitive info of course) Do you use the |DataDirectory| substitution string in your connectionstring?

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have to now read the database using a `select` statement, you cant use an `INSERT` SQL statement to read.

You could add the following immediately after your insert.

```
using(var selectCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nume,Prenume,Parola,Email FROM Clienti WHERE Nume = @Nume", cn))
{
    selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume", register_nume.Text);
    using(SqlDataReader reader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read()) { }
    }
}
```

That said if you want to know IF the row was inserted or how many records were inserted `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected. You could change that part of the code like this:

```
var recordsAffected = insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

if(recordsAffected > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Added succesfully");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing happened");
```

Although in this particular case it would not make sense because if nothing was inserted it would probably be caused by an Exception.

---

Some side notes

- Always wrap types that implement `IDisposable` in `using` blocks (see code above as example). It ensures that resources are always released as soon as you are done with them even if an Exception is thrown.
- Never swallow Exceptions! Either recover from one and log it or do not catch it at all. If you swallow it you will never know if/why your code broke.

Comment: Or an `INSERT` for that matter.

Comment: I am sorry for that but i am a noob could you be more precise?

Comment: @IonităM.Cătălin - I updated my answer. Create a 2nd command with a select and use that to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
       insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader reader = insert.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) { }
```

You only need the `ExecuteNonQuery`, it will run the INSERT. You need to use `ExecuteReader` *instead* only when you're running a statement that produces result sets (eg. `SELECT`). So it should be:

```
 insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is preparing the SQL command that you are running

```
cn.Open();
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand();
insert.CommandText = "insert into Clienti (Nume,Prenume,Parola,Email) values(@Nume,@Prenume,@Parola,@Email)";
insert.Connection = cn;
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume", register_nume.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenume", register_prenume.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parola", register_password.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", register_email.Text);
```

The SQL command that your code is running, is an `INSERT` statement, which only *adds a new record* to your table.

This statement runs the command that you setup earlier:

```
insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If I understand correctly, here you are trying to read the data from the table again:

```
SqlDataReader reader = insert.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) { }
```

Problem is, your command is NOT set for reading. To read data, you need to use a `SELECT` statement. Something like this:

```
insert.CommandText = "SELECT Nume,Prenume,Parola,Email from Clienti" ;
```

So, to read the data after executing the insert, you should do this:

```
insert.CommandText = "SELECT Nume,Prenume,Parola,Email from Clienti" ;
SqlDataReader reader = insert.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) { }
```

Comment: i am not trying to read the data again it is just that the database does not update after i finished completing my register_form via textboxes and i don't know why

Comment: So your insert statement is failing? Then you need to see what errors are thrown by DB. Do you land in the catch block?

Comment: My insert.ExecuteNonQuery() returns 1 but the information are not stored in database,i also have a login form and you can login with the dates that you just entered via register form but after stopping the debbugging the dates just vanish

Comment: Ok, here is what I suggest you to do... Put a break point after the insert.ExecuteNonQuery statement and check the table in database to make sure that your insert has actually added the record to the table. If it is added successfully and you can see it, then something else is deleting the record. If you don't see the record in the table, then your insert statement is failing. Let's check that before moving forward

Answer (score 0):

You ar executing 2 times the query:

```
insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataReader reader = insert.ExecuteReader();
```

Try to get the affected rows

```
int rows = insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I would suggest creating a stored procedure in your database and just execute the SP.

It's always better to execute SP from code and leave the SQL programming in the DB.